# What does this kind of a population graph mean?

Tags: distributions, interpretation, population

I have data for 131,653 users about how often they do a task, and how much time they take when doing the task. I simply arrange the number of times they do the task in ascending order of the time they take, and make a scatter plot. This is what I get:

[image]

I don't understand what to make of this pattern. I have not seen anything like this before. Can anyone help me understand what might be going on?

I can zoom into the graph to show the plot for users 10,000 to 20,000:

[image]

And also, this is the zoomed in plot for uers 130,000 to the end:

[image]

**EDIT:** The dataset looks something like this:

```
User   Time     Number of
ID     (sec)    occurrences

1       110     342
2       172     332
3       193     357
4       196     492
5       206     287
6       246     338
7       270     296
8       357     440
```

The time taken has been sorted in ascending order, as shown in the dataset, and the users have been marked with IDs according to the time. And then, I do the scatter plot of column 3, which is giving this bizarre pattern.

**EDIT 2:** Let me explain a bit about the context of the data. The task is opening of notifications and the time is the response delay (i.e., how long after receiving the notifications does the user open it). So, the response time ranges from 0 to 168 hours (i.e., 1 week, which is the duration for which the data was collected - and some notifications were never opened). So, I just took the raw data, sorted the records in increasing order of the response time, and plotted the number of times each user opened a notification. Hope the context is clearer now.

**EDIT 3:** Here is the graph of the number of occurrences vs the response time (note that the x-axis is in log scale, as in the linear scale all the points were cluttered near the origin):

[image]

Comment: what does it mean ''in ascending order of the time they take'' ?

Comment: @fcop I have edited the question to explain the data.

Comment: Are all users doing the same identical task ?

Comment: @fcop Yes. All users are doing the exact same task every time.

Comment: Some of what you are seeing could be due to discretization of time

Comment: I am afraid this is unanswerable without knowing: what exactly is your data, how was it measured, what kind of transformations did you apply, what exactly are the plots etc.

Comment: Like others I don't understand all the description here but I suspect a side-effect of using ratios based on integers. Only certain values are possible.

Comment: Ok, so let me explain a bit then about the context of the data. The task is opening of notifications and the time is the response delay (i.e., how long after receiving the notifications does the user open it). So, the response time ranges from 0 to 168 hours (i.e., 1 week, which is the duration for which the data was collected - and some notifications were never opened). So, I just took the raw data, sorted the records in increasing order of reaction time, and plotted the number of times each user opened a notification. Hope the context is clearer now.

Comment: I think it just shows that some users work slower than others ? an that ''in general'' the more taksks, the more time you need ? Can you make a scatter with the number of tasks on the horizontal axis and the time on the vertical ?

Comment: @fcop In general, yes. But what about the unexpected beautiful patterns we see here?

Comment: You order by time, so the 'L' shape learns that the fisrt one does a lot in a few time, then others take more time to do a bit less and then at a certain point in time you have again faster ones, can you make a scatter of the number of task on the horizontal axis and the time vertical ?

Comment: I plotted the  scatter of the number of task on the horizontal axis and the time vertical in the latest edit to the question, since I couldn't post the picture in the comments here.

Comment: So they get notifications and after a while they open it, do they have others tasks to do in the meantime ? Apparently the reaction time has some pattern so it could be that a user, after opening has to ''do something'' with it and only after that he can open the next one, if the ''do something'' with it is different or takes more time for some users than you can have this no ?

Comment: @fcop Hmmm, I don't know. These are data collected from real people, so after opening a notification, I guess they read the post whose notification they opened. Or they could do something else, the data doesn't say anything about it. But interesting point.

Comment: What is an "occurrence?" As I understand: (i) a user with a unique ID "userid" receives a notification (ii) he/she responds after "Time (sec)" seconds. What is the number of occurrences? Occurrences of what?

Comment: @Matthew initially I had not put in the edits, and tried to put the problem as simply as possible. Number of occurrences simply means the number of times a user opened notifications.